# Google Indexing AWS Network Interface IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a site running on ECS in AWS with the DNS being handled by Route53.

There are two network interfaces which I can use the Public IP addresses of to access the site. The problem is Google has indexed this IP addresses as well as the domain name.

How do I "redirect" the IP addresses to the domain name?

Comment: can you review the answers to see if it solves your question?

Comment: @tyron sorry was travelling - your answer helped massively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 aspects in your question:

1. You want your access using IP to resolve to your domain name
2. Google indexing your site with the wrong URL

For your 1st challenge, there isn't a native way to force browsers from IP back to URLs. You have to handle this in your application or infrastructure. Since you're running in ECS, that could either be a rule in a Load Balancer (e.g. if using Application Load Balancer, a rule that checks if Host-Header doesn't match your domain then redirect to your domain URL), or you could write the logic into your container.

Regarding the #2 problem, that might be because your IP was added to some site in the internet (remember that IPs are re-used in AWS), and as a result Google has the IP in the cache and it's refreshing it. To handle this problem, you might need to review if it's possible using [Google's Removals Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846).

Comment: This is good advice. In addition I would suggest adding a `rel=canonical` tag to every page on the website, which instructs Google and other search engines how ito ndex your site when there are multiple valid addresses for your site https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls